# How do I parse and store an integer value from a json dictionary in swift?

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, swift

I have parsed a JSON array and extracted an NSDictionary and from this have extracted a String variable and successfully passed this via a segue to my next view. When I try to do the same with an integer the app crashes...

This is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "genreSegue" {
        println("genreSegue")
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        println("row: \(indexPath.row)")
        var bookView:BookViewController = segue.destinationViewController as BookViewController

        if let genres = self.genreList as? [NSDictionary] {
            var item = genres[indexPath.row]
            println("segueItem: \(item)")
            let title:String = item["title"] as String
            let genreId:Int = item["id"] as Int  // this line crashes the app
            let genreId:NSNumber = item["id"] as NSNumber // this version also crashes
            println("title: \(title)")
            bookView.genreTitle = item["title"] as String
            //bookView.genreId = item["id"] as Int  // so I can't test this line
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
genreSegue
row: 1
segueItem: {
    id = 2;
    records = 1;
    selfLink = "http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~bookshop/v1.1/index.php/genre/id/2";
    title = Biography;
}
title: Biography
```

Here is the error on thread 1:
    libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:

Here is the original json data:

```
http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~bookshop/v1.1/index.php/genre/list
```

Here is my app source code:

```
https://github.com/marktyers/ios_bookshop_client
```

I don't see how the string variable works but not the int. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps, the crash report and the actual JSON would provide more info. ;)

Comment: Blind shot far: `NSJSONSerialization` gives you an `NSNumber` object. Maybe you are trying to assign it to a primitive `Int`?

Comment: Well spotted however having modified my code I get the same crash if I use NSNumber...

Comment: What happens if you try to convert it with `Int()` (instead of `as Int`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the number you are looking for is not a number in the JSON, it's a String. So try this:

```
let genreId = (item["id"] as String).toInt() // This casts the String to an Integer
                                             // Note that this is not Int but Int?
```

Here you see thats a string:

[image: Created with JSONView for Google Chrome]